# Калькулятор с RADIOBUTTON. Значение radiobutton отображается alert , но к сумме не подтягивается

Tags: javascript, radiobutton, value

Пыталась прописать переменные с value, но вышла лажа т.к   ещё только вникаю в синтаксис .

Код кидаю песочницей еще так думаю будет лучше .
https://codepen.io/EvaSpense/pen/xxZMRgr?editors=1111

```js
function raschitat() {

  radioV = document.getElementsByName('variant_cvet');

  for (i = 0; i < radioV.length; i++) {
    if (radioV[i].checked)

      alert(radioV[i].value);
  }

}

material = document.getElementById('material').value;
switch (material) {
  case "tree":
    cenaMaterial = 15000;
    break
  case "bereza":
    cenaMaterial = 16000;
    break
  case "dub":
    cenaMaterial = 17000;
    break

  case "buk":
    cenaMaterial = 18000;
    break

  case "yasen":
    cenaMaterial = 19000;
    break

  default:
    cenaMaterial = 15000;
    break
}





box = document.getElementById('box').value;
switch (box) {
  case "1":
    cenaBox = 400;
    break

  case "2":
    cenaBox = 500;
    break

  case "3":
    cenaBox = 600;
    break

  case "4":
    cenaBox = 700;
    break

  case "5":
    cenaBox = 800;
    break

  case "6":
    cenaBox = 900;
    break

  default:
    cenaBox = 400;
    break
}


place = document.getElementById('place').value;
switch (place) {
  case "1":
    cenaPlace = 1000;
    break

  case "2":
    cenaPlace = 2000;
    break

  default:
    cenaPlace = 1000;
    break

}

if (box == "") {
  alert("Вы не указали кол-во ящиков");
} else if (place == "") {
  alert("Вы не указали кол-во мест");
} else {

  size = document.getElementById('size').value;
  switch (size) {
    case "1":
      cenaSize = 300;
      break
    case "2":
      cenaSize = 600;
      break
    case "3":
      cenaSize = 700;
      break

    case "4":
      cenaSize = 900;
      break

    case "5":
      cenaSize = 1000;
      break

    default:
      cenaSize = 300;
      break
  }


  bortik = document.getElementById('bortik').value;
  switch (bortik) {
    case "no-bortik":
      cenaBortik = 0;
      break
    case "little bortik":
      cenaBortik = 250;
      break
    case "big bortik":
      cenaBortik = 260;
      break

    default:
      cenaBortik = 0;
      break
  }


  stoimost = (cenaMaterial) + (cenaBox) + (cenaPlace) + (cenaSize) + (cenaBortik) + (radioV);
  document.getElementById('stoimost').innerHTML = "Стоимость равна: " + stoimost + " р.";
}
```

```css
.cp_item {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}

img.icon {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Стандарт Юниор</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h3>Расчет стоимости кровати</h3>

  <p>Стандарт Юниор</p>

  <img src="C:\Users\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\КрСт Юн с быстросъем борт с ящ на кол прямох.jpg" width="400">

  <p>Материал</p>
  <div class="product-field-display">
    <select id="material">
      <option value="sosna">Сосна </option>
      <option value="bereza">Береза </option>
      <option value="dub">Дуб </option>
      <option value="buk">Бук </option>
      <option value="yasen">Ясень </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br>


  <p>Цвет</p>


  <div class="cp_item">

    <input type="radio" id="cvet" value="1" name="variant_cvet" checked>
    <img class="icon" src="C:\Users\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\stariy-oreh-3_500x500.jpg" alt="Старый орех 3">
    <span>Темный</span>

  </div>

  <div class="cp_item">

    <input type="radio" id="cvet" value="2" name="variant_cvet">
    <img class="icon" src="C:\Users\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\gr_oreh1_500x500 (1).jpg" alt="Грецкий орех 1">
    <span>Светлый</span>

  </div>

  <div class="cp_item">

    <input type="radio" id="cvet" value="3" name="variant_cvet">
    <img class="icon" src="C:\Users\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\mogano-3_500x500.jpg" alt="Могано">
    <span>Лак</span>

  </div>

  <div class="cp_item">

    <input id="cvet" type="radio" value="4" name="variant_cvet">
    <img class="icon" src="C:\Users\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\venge-1_500x500.jpg" alt="Венге">
    <span>Серый</span>

  </div>


  <div class="cp_item">

    <input id="cvet" type="radio" value="5" name="variant_cvet">
    <img class="icon" src="C:\Users\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\mogano-1_500x500.jpg" alt="Дерево 1">
    <span>Дерево 1</span>

  </div>

  <div class="cp_item">
    <input id="cvet" type="radio" value="6" name="variant_cvet">
    <img class="icon" src="C:\Users\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\mogano-3_500x500.jpg" alt="Дерево 2">
    <span>Дерево 2 </span>

  </div>


  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Кол-во ящиков</p>
  <div class="product-field-box">
    <select id="box">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>



  <br>
  <p>Кол-во спальных мест</p>
  <div class="product-field-place">
    <select id="place">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br>

  <p>Размер кровати</p>
  <div class="product-field-size">
    <select id="size">
      <option value="1">60x120 +300,00 руб</option>
      <option value="2">70x160 +600,00 руб</option>
      <option value="3">80x160 +700,00 руб</option>
      <option value="4">80x190 +900,00 руб</option>
      <option value="5">90x190 +1000,00 руб</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br>

  <p>Тип бортика</p>
  <div class="product-field-bortik">
    <select id="bortik">
      <option value="no-bortik">нет</option>
      <option value="little bortik">быстросъемный +250,00 руб</option>
      <option value="big bortik">стационарный +260,00 руб</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div><button onclick="raschitat();">Рассчитать стоимость</button></div>
  <br>
  <div id="stoimost"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//radioV = document.getElementsByName('variant_cvet');

//for (i = 0; i < radioV.length; i++) {
//  if (radioV[i].checked)
//    alert(radioV[i].value);
//  }
//}

let radioV = +document.querySelector('[name="variant_cvet"]:checked').value;
```

```js
function raschitat() {

  //radioV = document.getElementsByName('variant_cvet');
  //for (i = 0; i < radioV.length; i++) {
  //  if (radioV[i].checked)
  //    alert(radioV[i].value);
  //}
  //}
  let radioV = +document.querySelector('[name="variant_cvet"]:checked').value;

  material = document.getElementById('material').value;
  switch (material) {
    case "sosna":
      cenaMaterial = 15000;
      break
    case "bereza":
      cenaMaterial = 16000;
      break
    case "dub":
      cenaMaterial = 17000;
      break
    case "buk":
      cenaMaterial = 18000;
      break
    case "yasen":
      cenaMaterial = 19000;
      break
    default:
      cenaMaterial = 15000;
      break
  }

  box = document.getElementById('box').value;
  switch (box) {
    case "1":
      cenaBox = 400;
      break
    case "2":
      cenaBox = 500;
      break
    case "3":
      cenaBox = 600;
      break
    case "4":
      cenaBox = 700;
      break
    case "5":
      cenaBox = 800;
      break
    case "6":
      cenaBox = 900;
      break
    default:
      cenaBox = 400;
      break
  }

  place = document.getElementById('place').value;
  switch (place) {
    case "1":
      cenaPlace = 1000;
      break
    case "2":
      cenaPlace = 2000;
      break
    default:
      cenaPlace = 1000;
      break
  }

  if (box == "") {
    alert("Вы не указали кол-во ящиков");
  } else if (place == "") {
    alert("Вы не указали кол-во мест");
  } else {
    size = document.getElementById('size').value;
    switch (size) {
      case "1":
        cenaSize = 300;
        break
      case "2":
        cenaSize = 600;
        break
      case "3":
        cenaSize = 700;
        break
      case "4":
        cenaSize = 900;
        break
      case "5":
        cenaSize = 1000;
        break
      default:
        cenaSize = 300;
        break
    }

    bortik = document.getElementById('bortik').value;
    switch (bortik) {
      case "no-bortik":
        cenaBortik = 0;
        break
      case "little bortik":
        cenaBortik = 250;
        break
      case "big bortik":
        cenaBortik = 260;
        break
      default:
        cenaBortik = 0;
        break
    }

    stoimost = (cenaMaterial) + (cenaBox) + (cenaPlace) + (cenaSize) + (cenaBortik) + (radioV);
    document.getElementById('stoimost').innerHTML = "Стоимость равна: " + stoimost + " р.";
  }
}
```

```css
.cp_item {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}

img.icon {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Стандарт Юниор</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h3>Расчет стоимости кровати</h3>

  <p>Стандарт Юниор</p>

  <img src="C:\Users\Саша\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\КрСт Юн с быстросъем борт с ящ на кол прямох.jpg" width="400">

  <p>Материал</p>
  <div class="product-field-display">
    <select id="material">
      <option value="sosna">Сосна </option>
      <option value="bereza">Береза </option>
      <option value="dub">Дуб </option>
      <option value="buk">Бук </option>
      <option value="yasen">Ясень </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br>


  <p>Цвет</p>


  <div class="cp_item">

    <input type="radio" id="cvet" value="1" name="variant_cvet" checked>
    <img class="icon" src="C:\Users\Саша\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\stariy-oreh-3_500x500.jpg" alt="Старый орех 3">
    <span>Темный</span>

  </div>

  <div class="cp_item">

    <input type="radio" id="cvet" value="2" name="variant_cvet">
    <img class="icon" src="C:\Users\Саша\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\gr_oreh1_500x500 (1).jpg" alt="Грецкий орех 1">
    <span>Светлый</span>

  </div>

  <div class="cp_item">

    <input type="radio" id="cvet" value="3" name="variant_cvet">
    <img class="icon" src="C:\Users\Саша\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\mogano-3_500x500.jpg" alt="Могано">
    <span>Лак</span>

  </div>

  <div class="cp_item">

    <input id="cvet" type="radio" value="4" name="variant_cvet">
    <img class="icon" src="C:\Users\Саша\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\venge-1_500x500.jpg" alt="Венге">
    <span>Серый</span>

  </div>


  <div class="cp_item">

    <input id="cvet" type="radio" value="5" name="variant_cvet">
    <img class="icon" src="C:\Users\Саша\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\mogano-1_500x500.jpg" alt="Дерево 1">
    <span>Дерево 1</span>

  </div>

  <div class="cp_item">
    <input id="cvet" type="radio" value="6" name="variant_cvet">
    <img class="icon" src="C:\Users\Саша\Desktop\кровати калькулятор\mogano-3_500x500.jpg" alt="Дерево 2">
    <span>Дерево 2 </span>

  </div>


  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Кол-во ящиков</p>
  <div class="product-field-box">
    <select id="box">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>



  <br>
  <p>Кол-во спальных мест</p>
  <div class="product-field-place">
    <select id="place">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br>

  <p>Размер кровати</p>
  <div class="product-field-size">
    <select id="size">
      <option value="1">60x120 +300,00 руб</option>
      <option value="2">70x160 +600,00 руб</option>
      <option value="3">80x160 +700,00 руб</option>
      <option value="4">80x190 +900,00 руб</option>
      <option value="5">90x190 +1000,00 руб</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br>

  <p>Тип бортика</p>
  <div class="product-field-bortik">
    <select id="bortik">
      <option value="no-bortik">нет</option>
      <option value="little bortik">быстросъемный +250,00 руб</option>
      <option value="big bortik">стационарный +260,00 руб</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div><button onclick="raschitat();">Рассчитать стоимость</button></div>
  <br>
  <div id="stoimost"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: не работает :( можно больше подробностей ,пожалуйста

Comment: @АлександраВоробьёва Вы напутали со скобками.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!!:)))))))))

Comment: @АлександраВоробьёва Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.